# Does table columns increase select statement execution time

Tags: mysql, performance

I have 2 tables, same structure, same rows, same data but the first has more columns (fields).

For example:

I select the same 3 fields from both of them (SELECT a,b,c FROM mytable1 and then SELECT a,b,c FROM mytable2)

I've tried to run those queries on 100,000 records (for each table) but at the end I got the same execution time (0.0006 sec)
Do you know if the number of the columns (and in the end the size of the one table is bigger than the other) has to do something with the query execution time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically it would affect execution time and you could possibly see a difference if the data on the table with more columns is bigger. 
Ex. Table1:500mb, Table2:40mb.
Performance degrades especially if the dataset index no longer fits in memory. Then disk performance steps in.

Answer (score 1):

It would affect execution time, but I think a linear increase in column/row size would have a marginal effect.  Since MySQL still has to process/display the extra data there's no way it has zero effect.

The key point (in my opinion) would be to *only* select the columns and rows that you **need** to select.

Answer (score 1):

IMO. Selecting only right columns affect delivering time (from database server to application server) and affects memory because more data should be stored and transfered.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you're selecting the same three columns from the table.  There are a couple of ways that I can think of where having extra columns (but not selecting them) would have little/no impact:

1. If all the columns you're selecting are in the index, MySQL won't have to read the underlying row from disk.
2. If the new columns are VARCHAR, I believe the page sizes will be mostly unchanged (since VARCHARs are really pointers).
3. If the new columns are small (TINYINT, for example, is only 1 byte).

In general, a more narrow table will give you better performance.

If you want to try an example, toss in some large CHARs (not VARCHARs) and select those columns back in your test queries.  I would expect that to be worse.

Hope that helps.